# MDX Report for competitive analysis over markets

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have an reporting request I am trying to wrap my head around.  I know how I would accomplish this in T-SQL, but MDX is killing me!

The request :

Based on customer selected, find all markets they have a presence in, then find all customers in those markets and find average performance by the produces All customers in each market the selected customer is in.  This will allow our selected customer to gauge their performance per market against their competition in each market.

I'm not looking for an exact answer, more of how a general approach.

Answer (score 2):

Basket Analysis: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa902637